# Can change minsdkversion from 5 to 8 while updating the app on google play?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an Android app on Google Play market. I have added some features and also I want to change minsdkversion 5 to 8. Will Google play accept the new apk or reject due to increase in minsdkversion?

Answer (score 2):

Google Play will accept it, just as long as the package name and the signing certificate are the same, doesn't matter if the minSDK, targetSDK or maxSDK is changed within the manifest.

Answer (score 2):

it will accept and give you a warning letting you know how many users won't be able to update it.

Answer (score 0):

The devices from API version <=7 will not get any update but the devices >=8 API version  will get update as usual.